# Java DateFormat

Tags: java, date-format

I know Java Date Time is not a good way to go forward but I was just curious as to what's happening:

Why does the following line:

`DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US)`

not produce any errors and the following lines do:

`DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-YYYY", Locale.US)`

`DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-YYYY", Locale.US)`

The following exception gets thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'Y'

    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:769)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:576)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:501)
    at testing.MySchedule.main(MySchedule.java:18)
```

I mean I'm just changing the case right? but is DateFormat really that dumb or am I doing something wrong? or does it have something to do with the Locale I'm using?

Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`m` and `D` have their own meaning in SimpleDateFormat pattern:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
m   Minute in hour
D   Day in year
```

But you won't find `Y` in that table.

Answer (score 6):

You aren't changing only the case, you are changing the meaning of the format :

- `Y` doesn't exist.
- `M` stands for **Month in year**
- `m` stands for **Minute in hour**
- `D` stands for **Day in year**
- `d` stands for **Day in month**

`DD-MMM-YYYY` and `dd-mm-YYYY` formats have no meaning.

[More info on SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 5):

It's not "dumb", it's just an invalid pattern. Have a look at the API: 
[SimpleDateFormat - J2SE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) also SimpleDateFormat  usage has been updated in J2SE 7 and allows using Y now [SimpleDateFormat - J2SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#year

Comment: In particular "unquoted letters from 'A' to 'Z' and from 'a' to 'z' are interpreted as pattern letters".  "Y" isn't an allowed pattern.

Answer (score 1):

use (lowercase) y for year.

```
M = month
m = minute
d = 1-30 (or 31)
D = 1-365
```